# Oracle SQL Select date range when dates are in varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle, select

How should look Select date range when dates are in varchar2 dd/mm/yyyy?

When I use:

```
SELECT * FROM invoice
WHERE data_doc >= '01/07/2020'
AND data_doc <= '19/07/2020'
```

Returns values where data_doc is i.e. = 02/03/2020

Comment: You should try it with TO_TIMESTAMP. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm

Comment: Do you have any chance to fix that broken data model and convert the columns to proper `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare strings (`varchar2`'s in this case), you compare them lexicographically. One approach would be to convert those strings to actual dates:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   invoice
WHERE  TO_DATE(data_doc, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= TO_DATE('01/07/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
       TO_DATE(data_doc, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE('19/07/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: yeah but Mureinik forgot '/' in dates ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use TO_DATE conversions everywhere

```
SELECT * FROM invoice
WHERE TO_DATE(data_doc,'DD/MM/YYYY') >= TO_DATE('01/07/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') 
  AND TO_DATE(data_doc,'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE('19/07/2020','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

You (alas) need to convert the column to dates.  The comparison can then be done directly to dates:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(data_doc, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= DATE '2020-07-01' AND
      TO_DATE(date_doc, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= DATE '2020-07-17'
```

For performance, Oracle supports indexes on expressions.  So, you can create an index on `TO_DATE(data_doc, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`.

That said, you should fix your data model so dates are stored correctly as dates.

Because you are comparing dates in the same month -- and only for that reason -- you can adjust your comparison by requiring that the data be in the same month:

```
WHERE data_doc >= '01/07/2020' AND
      data_doc <= '19/07/2020' AND
      data_doc LIKE '__/07/2020'
```

I strongly recommend that you fix the data type, though.